# How to get coordinates of two different points using mouse click in 16-bit DOS code

Tags: assembly, mouse, interrupt, x86-16

So I am trying to get two different x coordinates in dosbox using mouse interrupt but it stops at the first click and I can't figure out how to fix it. I did try resetting the mouse, but did not work and the two coordinates I am displaying end up the same after the first click then program ends

```
main proc
mov ah,00h
    mov al,12h
    int 10h

;;mouse press 1
call mose
mov dx,x1
add dl,48
mov ah,02h 
int 21h

;; mouse press 2
call mose
mov dx,x1
add dl,48
mov ah,02h 
int 21h

jmp endi
main endp


mose proc
mov ax,0
aga:
mov ax,5
int 33h

cmp ax,1
je plce
jmp aga

plce:
mov ax,3
int 33h
mov x1,cx
mov y1,dx
ret
mose endp



endi:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33-5.html), you might not want to just check for ax = 1.  ax is a bitmapped field.  So while you want to know if the first bit is set, you don't want to make assumptions about all the other bits.  Also, bx is supposed to be set to either 0 or 1, but you don't set it to anything.  So who knows what it might contain?

Comment: Ohhhh I did not knew that since I am new to assembly and my teacher told me to check ax and not bx. The code works now, thank you!